# How does numpy scalar multiplication work?

Tags: python, numpy

I'm just curious about how numpy implements its scalar multiplication. In my understanding,
`x * y`  calls the `__mul__` method of x, `x.__mul__(y)`.

How would this work with this code:

```
x = 6
y = np.array([1,2])
print(x * y)
```

Wouldn't the code call `x.__mul__(y)`? And since x is not a numpy variable, how does numpy have any control over how this behaves?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When Python encounters `x * y` it will indeed first call [`x.__mul__(y)`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__mul__)<sup>(1)</sup>. Any such method may return [`NotImplemented`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/constants.html#NotImplemented) if it doesn't know how to handle the operand it received. This is what `x.__mul__(y)` does :

```py
>>> x = 6
>>> y = np.array([1, 2])
>>> x.__mul__(y)
NotImplemented
```

Then, as a next step, Python calls the reflected operands method [`__rmul__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__rmul__), i.e. `y.__rmul__(x)`:

```py
>>> y.__rmul__(x)
array([ 6, 12])
```

So in this second step, it is up to the `np.ndarray` class to determine the outcome of this operation <sup>(2)</sup>.

This can also be visualized with the help of a custom test class:

```py
>>> class Test:
...     def __rmul__(self, other):
...         print('__rmul__', self, other)
... 
>>> x = 1
>>> y = Test()
>>> x.__mul__(y)
NotImplemented
>>> x * y
__rmul__ <__main__.Test object at 0x7f46c6acb668> 1
```

---

<sub>(1) Unless `type(y)` is a subclass of `type(x)` in which case `y.__rmul__(x)` takes precedence over `x.__mul__(y)`.</sub>

<sub>(2) If both methods, `x.__mul__` and `y.__rmul__`, return `NotImplemented` then a `TypeError` is raised.</sub>